# HTTP Status (canceled) when autoplay, loop are true on HTML video element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

**Using Dev tools on Google Chrome Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit)**

I am playing with HTML5 video and saw in the Network activity that whenever the video looped it would show up with Status (canceled).

[image: Status (canceled)]

What is going on here? Is it re-downloading each time it loops back?

The attributes I use are `preload="none"` to prevent automatically downloading the video, `autoplay`, and `loop`.

**Here is some sample HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>fadeIn demo</title>
    <style>

    .video-container {
        display: none;
    }
    span {
        display: none;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="text-align:center">
        <div class="still-container">
            <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/collectememe/storage/video_still/4101688e-14fa-4018-b296-1514dc0d202f.jpeg" width="560">
        </div>
        <div class="video-container">
            <video id="video1" width="560" preload="none" autoplay loop poster="test.jpeg">
                <source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/collectememe/storage/video/4101688e-14fa-4018-b296-1514dc0d202f.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
            </video>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <script> 
        var video = document.getElementById("video1"); 
        $( ".still-container" ).click(function() {
            $(".still-container").hide();
            $( ".video-container" ).fadeIn( 1000, function() {
            });
            return false;
        });
    </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post a pic of the response headers for the video? My guess is that the player is checking the caching hash for any changes in the link

Comment: @Skarlinski http://i.imgur.com/tyk1Q9f.png

Comment: This is how it looks when it is served locally, does the same happen when you serve locally?
I see it's local by file://

Comment: @Skarlinski when I throw it on S3 I see no network activity at all for the mp4 file: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/playbucket01/testvideoembed.html

Comment: @eht Open up Chrome in incognito mode and you will see the mp4 in network activity. It does not have the same issue you are experiencing locally. 


I believe what you are experiencing locally is that you are not running a web server to serve up your html file and the browser cannot check to see if the file changed on loop.

Comment: @landro I think you're right. The mp4 file is grabbed from disk (HTTP 206) when I host it on s3 (https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/playbucket01/testvideoembed.html). I still find it odd that I don't see the initial download in the network activity. I didn't realize `preload="none"` hides the initial download then 206's from cache on loop.  If you want to fashion your comment in to an answer I'll award the bounty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open up Chrome in incognito mode and you will see the mp4 in network activity. It does not have the same issue you are experiencing locally. I believe what you are experiencing locally is that you are not running a web server to serve up your html file and the browser cannot check to see if the file changed on loop.